# In Snapshot how should i able to access (in Salesforce) the historical data as of the date it was captured

Tags: community, administration, customization

I have created snapshot and mapped all the fields (Source and Target) and scheduled the time also.

I am getting the proper output in report format also.

But now i want the "we should be able to access (in Salesforce) the historical data as of the **date it was captured**"

Comment: are you talking about SFDC Analytic Snapshots? A more specific example in your question would be helpful as this is question not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to filter the data on the date the data was captured from your report to your snapshot custom object. I have also looked at using formula fields to help filter by week or month name as part of the snapshot data set. Let me know the reporting scenario and I can try and further elaborate how to get the data out of your snapshot object/data. Opportunity reports are good for looking at the data at a point of time whereas an 'Installed Asset' report would look at a particular field over time.

And funny, I didn't know DreamFactory also had a product called SnapShot though I'm 99% sure this is the SFDC snapshot functionality.

Comment: Yes this would be SFDC analytic snapshots, since it's source/target mapping + scheduled job. What you are essentially doing here is setting up a job that copies data from source object to target object. So to report on the data as of a certain date/time, if you use the CreatedDate from the target object, that is the created date of the record, as at the time the snapshot job ran. This is what you will need to pull into a report.

Answer (score 0):

Sachin,
I am not sure what you mean by historical data. Do you mean Created By/ Date, Last Modified By/ Date etc.? If so, you can do that by using the Asset History Report. If you mean something else, I will need to speak with you to understand that better. Please contact me at sridhar at dreamfactory dot com or contact our support (support at dreamfactory dot com).

By the way, this forum is usually meant for Salesforce questions and not SnapShot related questions (We are happy to help wherever but other forum users might have a problem). So, please use DreamFactory Support (email is above) directly.

Thank you.